# How to replace text with index value in C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file which contains a repeated string called "map" for more than 800 now I would like to replace them with map to map0, map1, map2, .....map800.

I tried this way but it didn't work for me:

```
void Main()    {
 string text = File.ReadAllText(@"T:\File1.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
       {
         text = text.Replace("map", "map"+i);
       }
  File.WriteAllText(@"T:\File1.txt", text);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: why are you going to 2000 in for loop?

Comment: What didn't work about your code? (I bet you ended up with `map1999` replacing them all?) Your code isn't doing what you think it's doing, follow it closely for a few iterations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
void Main() {

    string text = File.ReadAllText(@"T:\File1.txt");
    int num = 0;

    text = (Regex.Replace(text, "map", delegate(Match m) {
        return "map" + num++;
    }));

    File.WriteAllText(@"T:\File1.txt", text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks amit yeah this is working but is there any way to write to the file instead if consul?

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces each existing key within the original string by adding a number to it.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="original">The original string.</param>
/// <param name="key">The key we are searching for.</param>
/// <param name="offset">The offset of the number we want to start with. The default value is 0.</param>
/// <param name="increment">The increment of the number.</param>
/// <returns>A new string where each key has been extended with a number string with "offset" and beeing incremented with "increment".The default value is 1.</returns>
/// <example>
/// Assuming that we have an original string of "mapmapmapmap" and the key "map" we
/// would get "map0map1map2map3" as result.
/// </example>
public static string AddNumberToKeyInString(string original, string key, int offset = 0, int increment = 1)
{
    if (original.Contains(key))
    {
        int counter = offset;
        int position = 0;
        int index;

        // While we are withing the length of the string and
        // the "key" we are searching for exists at least once
        while (position < original.Length && (index = original.Substring(position).IndexOf(key)) != -1)
        {
            // Insert the counter after the "key"
            original = original.Insert(position + key.Length, counter.ToString());
            position += index + key.Length + counter.ToString().Length;
            counter += increment;
        }
     }

     return original;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are replacing the same occurrence of map each time. So the resulting string will have map9876543210 map9876543210 map9876543210 for 10 iterations, if the original string was "map map map". You need to find each individual occurrence of map, and replace it. Try using the indexof method.

Answer (score -1):

Something along these lines should give you an idea of what you're trying to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\map.txt");
        int mapIndex = text.IndexOf("map");
        int hitCount = 0;
        int hitTextLength = 1;
        while (mapIndex >= 0 )
        {
            text = text.Substring(0, mapIndex) + "map" + hitCount++.ToString() + text.Substring(mapIndex + 2 + hitTextLength);
            mapIndex = text.IndexOf("map", mapIndex + 3 + hitTextLength);
            hitTextLength = hitCount.ToString().Length;
        }
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\map1.txt", text);
    }
```

Due to the fact that strings are immutable this wouldn't be the ideal way to deal with large files (1MB+) as you would be creating and disposing the entire string for each instance of "map" in the file.

For an example file:

```
map hat dog
dog map cat

lost cat map

mapmapmaphat

map
```

You get the results:

```
map0 hat dog
dog map1 cat

lost cat map2

map3map4map5hat

map6
```

Comment: it seems it stuck on text = text.Substring(0,mapIndex)+"map"+ hitCount++.ToString();
    mapIndex = text.IndexOf("map") + 3 + hitCount.ToString().Length;

Comment: Had to fix my code but added an example to clarify assumptions